# StringBuilder insufficient memory C#

Tags: c#

Here is what I am trying to achieve. Looping through a dataset over 1 million records and create a data dump in text file export to C drive.

I am looping through a dataset with over a million of records. Here is what is inside the loop

I am using a `StringBuilder` inside the loop.

```
myString.Append(ds.tables[0](i)(0));  <-- each datarow is not more than 10 char long.
```

It throws an error saying insufficient memory. I have 12 gb of Ram.

How do I go about fixing this problem?

Comment: Have you considered writing in batches, instead of trying to write the whole thing at once?

Answer (score 7):

Don't use an intermediate `StringBuilder` -- its contents sit in your computer's RAM before you presumably call `.ToString()` on it to write the result to disk. Instead, write the data to disk as you are processing it, something like:

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath, true)) 
{
    // start loop
        sw.Write(ds.tables[0](i)(0));
    // end loop
}
```

This will write text to a file using the default encoding (UTF-8) and buffer size (I think it's 4KB).

Answer (score 3):

Why do you store the large string in memory at all? If all you want to do is to write it to a text-file you could use a [`StreamWriter` to write](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce2kyyb4(v=vs.110).aspx) in batches:

```
using(var writer = new StreamWriter("c:\\file.txt", true))
{
    for(int rowNum = 0; rowNum < ds.tables[0].Rows.Count; rowNum++)
    {
        DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].Rows[rowNum];
        writer.Write(row.Field<string>(0));
    }
}
```

But maybe you can optimze it further. Do you really need the large `DataSet` at all? If the data came from a database you could use a `DataReader` to stream it lazily. Then you can write to the text-file without memory.

Comment: If you are looping through it, will the current write overwrite the existing file. I want each increment to append to the existing file. That is why I am using a StringBuilder to hold up everything and then write it to a StreamWriter.

Comment: And thats why i have used the constructor that takes a bool ;)  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

This means that CLR cannot allocate an object with the size you've requested. Each process has its own RAM limit so appending a million records to a StringBuilder is probably not possible on your machine or any standard machine.

Even if you have a lot of memory, and even if you're running a 64-bit CLR, there are limits to the size of objects that can be created.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you try to have your file in memory. But it's too large to hold it in memory. Now, you don't need to have it in memory all at once. You need to create smaller chunks (like you already do, for example lines) and instead of keeping all of them in memory at the same time, write them to disk and then "forget" about them, so that you only need the memory for one chunk, never for all chunks at the same time.

You can do that using LinQ because of a feature called deferred execution:

```
var collectionToBeIterated = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Select(r => r[0].ToString());

File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\your.file", collectionToBeIterated);
```

Note the absence of any method that would actually materialize the collection, like `ToList()` or `ToArray()` which would have the same problems your code has. This simply creates a description of what to do *when* the datasets rows get iterated. *Not* a command to actually do it all at once.